# How to perform a bulk-delete in OpenStack Swift

Tags: http-post, openstack

I am attempting to write an api that interacts with an OpenStack cluster for a suite of tools and am looking into bulk-delete so I can avoid thousands of requests to the server.

According to my interpretation of the OpenStack documentation for [bulk-delete](http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-object-storage/1.0/content/bulk-delete.html) I am doing the following:

1. using a url similar to this one: `http://ipaddress/v1/files/container-name?bulk-delete=true`
2. encoding my object names (which do exist):

   dps/filename.txt
   dps/filename1.txt
   dps/filename2.txt
   **as**
   dps%2Ffilename.txt%0Adps%2Ffilename1.txt%0Adps%2Ffilename2.txt

   and including them in the request body
3. setting the `content-type` to `text/plain` in the headers
4. sending in my auth token, of course, like always

After completing this request I get a *204 - No Content* response which doesn't match the documentation for what response I should receive. Also, no files are deleted which is the real problem.

Any ideas for what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Same here. Have you found a solution to fix that?

Comment: Well as the below answer suggests, my request was not well-formed. Our system also had an additional issue. We didn't have bulk-delete enabled. You can query the server to see if it supports bulk-delete. The first line in [the documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-object-storage/1.0/content/bulk-delete.html) shows how you can discover this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URI for sending the request should not include the name of the container.

Also, there are two problems with the request body you are sending.

1. Do not encode the `/` character between the container name and the object name.
2. Do not encode the newline characters.

The algorithm to produce the request body should actually go in this order:

1. Encode the container names.
2. Encode the object names.
3. Create a line of text `container/object` using the encoded names from the previous steps.
4. Create the request body by separating each of the lines from step 3 with a line feed character.

Comment: Good to know. It still will not delete by sending them like this though:
dps/filename.txt
dps/filename1.txt (with a newline)

Comment: @carpenter I edited my answer to include the first line, where you are also sending the request to the wrong URI.